# Render time of my page

Tags: php, rendering

Is there any way to get a php script that measures the localhost page rendering time. I have looked around but didn't find anything, maybe because I don't know how to search for this kind of script.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the time it takes the server to generate the HTML, or the time it takes the browser to render that HTML on screen?

Comment: hello, i am trying to get the render time needed to the browser to render that html on screen, thank you

Comment: you need firebug -- http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 20):

Update on original approved answer (for future people 'Googling' and cut-n-paste mojo):

For PHP 5.X+, you not only have to add 'true' as a parameter to both microtime() vars, but we don't have to divide it by 1,000 anymore. So the 2013 answer is:

Start of script:

```
$start = microtime(true);
```

Bottom of script:

```
$end = microtime(true);
$creationtime = ($end - $start);
printf("Page created in %.6f seconds.", $creationtime);
```

Comment: Hmm... I never check this, but perhaps I should.  What's a good target benchmark for a shared host?  Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: Maybe things were different *back in 2013* but here in *the future*, this method will tell you how long the PHP script took to run, but **it does *not* take page rendering into account** (like the OP asked).  Depending on the browser, cache, and number of images, etc., to be loaded, page rendering might not be complete until long after the PHP script has finished executing.

Comment: @ashleedawg The term 'rendering' here is used to describe generating the HTML output on the server side, not the graphical rendering of the page on the client machine.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to figure out how long it took your server to create the page (for example, to display this to the user), then you'll want to put this at the start of the code:

```
$start = microtime();
```

And then at the end put this:

```
$end = microtime();
$creationtime = ($end - $start) / 1000;
printf("Page created in %.5f seconds.", $creationtime);
```

Comment: hello, i have puted $start = microtime(); at my header.php, and the other script at the end of the page, at footer.php, but i see that the time is too low Page created in 0.000286066 seconds.but this is not true, i count that the page need about 3-4 seconds or more ro generate.. any thing wrong ? thank you

Comment: Well, this time is the actual time that PHP works on creating the page, and the only one that can be measured as far as I know. The time between the user requesting the page and the user actually seeing it will have a whole lot of other things involved in it - the request to the webserver (usually this is fast, but if the webserver is overloaded, it may be slow), the actual sending of the page, and finally the user's browser rendering the HTML. I would assume that what is slowing down the outputting of the page is one of those things.

Comment: hello, i am trying to get the render time needed to the browser to render that html on screen, thank you

Comment: If you are on PHP 5+ you need to add true as a parameter to microtime - otherwise you will be trying to do math on strings.

Comment: This method will tell you how long the PHP script took to run, but **it does *not* take page rendering into account** (like the OP asked).  Depending on the browser, cache, and number of images/videos/fonts, etc., to be loaded, page rendering might not be complete until *long* after the PHP script has finished executing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't measure the browser rendering time with PHP. All you can do is measure the time it takes the server to generate the page.

However if using javascript is ok, you can do the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var start_time=+new Date();
        window.onload=function(){
            alert("Page render time: " + ((+new Date()-start_time)/1000));
        };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hi</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want a browser plugin, look here:
[measure page rendering time on IE 6 or FF 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782438/measure-page-rendering-time-on-ie-6-or-ff-3-x)

Comment: Thanks! (the other answers don't answer the OP's questions and therefore are incorrect)